# Pagespeed Insights page score drops using Adsense

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, adsense, pagespeed

I wish to add ads to my webpage: https://www.gamestegy.com, however there is an issue. Once I added the script tag suggested by the adsense, my page score dropped by 10-20 points. Moreover, I started receiving these issues from Pagespeed analysis:

[image]

I am using nuxt js application (if that has any effect) and my script tag for getting AdSense looks like this:

```
<script data-n-head="ssr" src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" data-ad-client="ca-pub-3965267899600337" async="" defer="" data-checked-head="true"></script>
```

I tried to use defer and no defer but that had the same effect. What are my options here to improve the score? Or how can I better understand the issue here?

Regards,
Rokas

Comment: The issue is that ads scripts are a huge bloated mess. If you want a performant site, don't use Google ads. If you want to have ads, first party serving them from your server is your best option performance wise.

Comment: @Nit You mean introducing my own system/platform for serving ads on the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

The defer script attribute causes Javascript to execute just before the page loads. You can use the code below to load AdSense after the page loads.

```
function adSense() {
  var e=document.createElement("script")
  e.src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"
  e.setAttribute("data-ad-client","ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
  document.body.appendChild(e)
}

window.addEventListener("load",adSense)
```

This doesn't fix PageSpeed score, however it significantly improves Document Complete time in WebPageTest.